# Manual sorting in tx_news Typo3

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, tx-news

I use the Tx_news Extension (not TT_news) and have 2 pages where i show my newsitems. On Home I show only some topnews with the Listview, and there is a second page with the full News overview, the last one is ordered by Date & Time field.
But for the items on the Home I want a Manual sorting if it's possible.

I have added the following code in my resources:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXT']['news']['orderByNews'] .= ",sorting";
```

This gives in the plugin the option for Manual Sorting, so that part works. Only How and Where can I order the News Items?

*Note: I see in the Newsrecord table (tx_news_domain_model_news) the column sorting, my records are all 0 in there, I think its something with this, but can't get my finger on it.*

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the news-plugin settings in ts-setup.

```
plugin.tx_news {
    settings {
        orderBy = sorting
        orderDirection = desc
        orderByAllowed = sorting,author,uid,title,teaser,author,tstamp,crdate,datetime,categories.title
}
```

}

Comment: Not needed. Solution was a bit simpler... Plugin has a checkbox for Manual sorting. Turned that on and it worked!

Comment: You can do this also but it´s only per plugin. If you have multiple plugins on a site it´s better to have one single point where you can change the setting.